# Prevent bash alias from evaluating statement at shell start

Tags: bash, alias

Say I have the following alias.

```
alias pwd_alias='echo `pwd`'
```

This alias is not "dynamic". It evaluates `pwd` as soon as the shell starts. Is there anyway to delay the evaluation of the expression in the ticks until the alias's runtime?

Comment: The single quotes should do that (and they do on my system).

Comment: `alias pwd_alias='echo $PWD'`

Answer (score 43, accepted):

What you really want is a function, instead of an alias.

```
pwd_alias() {
   echo "$PWD"
}
```

Aliases do nothing more than replace text. Anything with complexity calls for a function.

Comment: Where do you put this function in order to work as an alias? In a file in /usr/local/bin, or you can put it like that in .bashrc?

Comment: @dgilperez `~/.bashrc` is fine.

Comment: This function syntax didn't work for me. I had to use 
`function pwd_alias {
    echo "$PWD"
}`

Comment: @JosephKiran the function syntax in the answer is the POSIX syntax. When putting it on one line you need `;` eg `pwd_alias() { echo "$PWD"; }`.

Comment: @jordanm Please excuse the semicolon. I wrote it in multiple lines in the comment but it got formatted into a single line. What I meant to ask was, I required the `function` keyword in the definition. I got a syntax error at  the first parenthesis when I tried the syntax in the answer in my .bashrc file.

Answer (score 4):

As jordanm said, aliases do nothing more than replace text.
If you want the argument of echo to be the output of pwd expanded by bash, then I don't understand your question.
If you want the argument of echo to be `pwd` with the backquotes kept, it's indeed possible, for example:

```
alias a="echo '\`pwd\`'"
```

So, if instead of echo you have something which does backquote expansion in its own runtime, maybe that's what you want.

Comment: The above doesn't work, you need to remove the single quotes:  `alias a="echo \\`pwd\\`"`

Comment: Yes it does work as I intended, when you invoke a the shell echoes `pwd` with the backquotes kept.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe you can change the evaluation from occurring at shell start.  Since the processes of creating the alias is run at shell start the `pwd` is evaluated then.  You could simple change the alias to just run `pwd` without the back ticks as `pwd` outputs without the need to echo.  A simple way to resolve this is to change from using an alias to a shell script in your path if you do not wish to change from using an alias.

```
#!/bin/bash
pwd
```