# How to stop alias from being evaluated on boot

Tags: linux, bash, operating-system

So I have an alias that goes like this

```
alias sshttomynode="ssh $(knife node list | grep my-node)"
```

Everytime I start a new terminal session and my vpn is not connected I get an error because the `knife` commands is a cli to for the chef server.

Since aliases are meant to be on demand and not to run on boot why is it being evaulated? How can I rewrite this to avoid this issue?

Comment: I define it .bashrc although i source it from .zshrc

Comment: Use single quotes instead?

Comment: You could try a function instead of an alias, https://stackoverflow.com/a/13261212/488095